# Why does word macro behaviour change when used in conjunction with track changes?

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

A recent issue I noticed when running word macros (in this case specifically search and replace operations), is that they don't have the expected behaviour when track changes is activated (it makes sense to me to activate it, so I can more easily track the changes that happened in a document due to the macro, thus having an easier time ascertaining its performance). I have the following code (this is just an example to demonstrate the issue):

```
Sub test()

ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = Not ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions

With Selection.Find
    .Text = "(B)([0-9]{6})"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1 \2"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

With Selection.Find
    .Text = "(organised)(  )(under)"
    .Replacement.Text = "\1 \3"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```

What the first selection.find does is find numbers such as these

```
B666666
```

and replace them with

```
B 666666
```

what the second search and replace does is find a very specific part of the text where there is a double space and replaces it with a single space

```
organised  under
```

is changed to

```
organised under
```

both of these codes work. But if I activate track changes before running the code using

```
ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = Not ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions
```

then the first part of the code results in

```
"B666666 " 'thus it does nothing except for putting a space in front of the string
```

and the second code does the following

```
"organisedunder " 'thus it merges the two strings and puts a space in front of them.
```

Can someone explain this change in the behaviour and whether there is a way to prevent this, other than not having track changes activated?

Solution? :

```
Sub EvenMoreTesting()

Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

With Selection
.Find.Text = "Stocks"

Do
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
Found = .Find.Execute
If Found Then Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
If Found Then Selection.TypeText Text:="Sto"
Loop While Found

End With

End Sub
```